# Custom tableview cell not deselecting when I return?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I created a custom table view cell. I added a black transparent overlay image for when the user presses the cell. It works great, however, when you go back to the tableview the cell is still selected. Here is my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell: PackCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! PackCell
    selectedCell.highlightImage.isHidden = false

    performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifiers[indexPath.row], sender: self)

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: `highlightImage ` is your custom overlay?

Comment: @KarloA.López yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should also hide your highlightImage when come back?

```
selectedCell.highlightImage.isHidden = true
```

Comment: I have this in my cellForRowAt function. Should I place it somewhere else?

Comment: Then you can try tableView.reloadData() in viewWillAppear when you come back. That will update your tableview and call cellForRowAt

Comment: That worked! One more question (marking current question as answered). I actually placed this code in didHighlightRowAt instead so that it would only appear when highlighted. However, when I hold down on a cell and begin to scroll, then let go, it doesn't perform the segue and just keeps the cell highlighted. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: When you touch a cell and hold, it will call didHighlightRowAt, not didSelectRowAt. So that's why you see your cell highlight, but it doesn't perform the segue. You may want to hide you highlight image in didUnhighlightRowAt. Hope this answer your question.

Comment: It performs the segue, but only if I don’t scroll while the cell is highlighted.